# Insert draggable dynamic

Tags: jquery

First, sorry for my english.

My problem is the following:

I have 3 list, and drag to the list 1 for the 2, and the list 2 for list 3, but if I add items in the list 1 dynamic, I can not drag, here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Pedidos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
width: 150px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#cozinha li, #garcom li").draggable({
        revert : "invalid",
        containment : "document",
        helper : "clone",
        cursor : "crosshair"
    });
    $("#garcom ol").droppable({
        activeClass : "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass : "ui-state-hover",
        accept : "#cozinha li",
        greedy : true,
        drop : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    }).sortable({
        items : "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort : function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
    $("#caixa ol").droppable({
        activeClass : "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass : "ui-state-hover",
        accept : "#garcom li",
        greedy : true,
        drop : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    }).sortable({
        items : "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort : function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON('pedidos', function(events) {
            for ( var i in events) {
                $('#cozinha ol').append(
                        '<li class="ui-state-highlight">' + events[i]
                                + '</li>');
            }
        });
    }, 6000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cozinha">
    <ol style="float: left; width: 30%">
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="garcom">
    <ol style="float: left; width: 30%">
        <li class="placeholder">Adicione Aqui</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="caixa">
    <ol style="float: left; width: 30%" class="sortable-class">
        <li class="placeholder">Adicione Aqui</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you add items to list 1? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The draggable code is not initialized against the new elements that you add to the DOM -- you must initialize them also. Here's one way to do that quickly:

Create a function in which you initialize the drag-drop-sortable elements. After inserting a new element, you will need to re-run that function.

<kbd>[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gcbPC/)</kbd>

Note that I also added an ID to the `<ol>` element just to make it easier to select.

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Pedidos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
width: 150px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#mybutt').click(function() {
        $('#bonk').append('<li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 6</li>');
        dragdropinit();
    });
    dragdropinit();
}); //END document.ready
function dragdropinit() {
    $("#cozinha li, #garcom li").draggable({
        revert : "invalid",
        containment : "document",
        helper : "clone",
        cursor : "crosshair"
    });
    $("#garcom ol").droppable({
        activeClass : "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass : "ui-state-hover",
        accept : "#cozinha li",
        greedy : true,
        drop : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    }).sortable({
        items : "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort : function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
    $("#caixa ol").droppable({
        activeClass : "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass : "ui-state-hover",
        accept : "#garcom li",
        greedy : true,
        drop : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    }).sortable({
        items : "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort : function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON('pedidos', function(events) {
            for ( var i in events) {
                $('#cozinha ol').append(
                        '<li class="ui-state-highlight">' + events[i]
                                + '</li>');
            }
        });
    }, 6000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cozinha">
    <ol id="bonk" style="float: left; width: 30%">
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Col3 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="garcom">
    <ol style="float: left; width: 30%">
        <li class="placeholder">Adicione Aqui</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="caixa">
    <ol style="float: left; width: 30%" class="sortable-class">
        <li class="placeholder">Adicione Aqui</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Add new col">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run code like this:

```
$("#cozinha li, #garcom li").draggable({
        revert : "invalid",
        containment : "document",
        helper : "clone",
        cursor : "crosshair"
    });
```

jQuery will find all li-elements under the element with id #cozinha and #garcom. Then jQuery will add events to those elements and make them draggable. Then it's done. So if you add new elements after this code is run, they will not be affected.

The solution is to make the new element draggable also after whey are added.